# UI hints that prevent user errors

Tags: user-interface

What UI/GUI guidelines should be followed that subtly (or not so subtly) direct users so they don't shoot themselves in the foot.

For instance, you might want to give power users the ability to "clean" a database of infrequently used records, but you don't want a new user to try out that option if they've just spent hours entering new records - they may lose them all because they're 'infrequently used'.  Please don't address this specific issue - it's just here to clarify the question.

While one could code a bunch of business logic in place to prevent some issues, you can't account for everything a user might do.

- **What are some common techniques, tips, and tricks that prevent improper usage?**

  - ie, How should I design the interface to alert users that a function or action is to be taken with care
- **What should I design in that limits risk and exposure if a poor action is taken?**

-Adam

Comment: Ha. Picky stackoverflowians. I think there should be a case study of the social norms being enforced by the community.

Comment: +1. @devinb - are you familiar with a short story called The Lottery? :)

Comment: I am now. Good ol' wisdom of the crowds. Chilling.

Comment: Thanks for directing me to it.

Comment: @devinb - It's simple - some people are unable to separate the intent from presentation.  Same reason poorly worded questions get downvoted.  My brand of humor is certainly far from universal, and the double entendre was too easily missed.  Changing the question very easily removes the distraction.

Comment: Usability of your question perhaps...? This has layers. I like that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Everything can be undone.  Don't erase - deactivate.  Back up before every destructive operation, and give the user a way to restore.

That's the path.  It's hard to follow it all the way, but it's what you're aiming for.

Comment: There was an early guideline at Apple: "It's hard to be easy."

Answer (score 10):

Make it possible to undo dangerous actions.

If it's a reasonably big application or system, require separate admin access for dangerous operations as well.

Answer (score 8):

[Don't Make Me Think](http://www.sensible.com/)

And you can, in fact you HAVE to account for everything they might do. Because you (as the designer) as the one who gives them the ability to do all those things.

Before putting ANY item on a gui as yourself "Can this be misused?" and if it can, you might want to go with a lower level of customizability.
Example hierarchy

- Button - Can be clicked.
- T/F Radio Button (mandatory) - Only two options.
- Combo Box - Many options, possibly "no option". more confusing.
- Text field - Myriad of wildly inconsistent options. More confusing for user, more dangerous for coder.

Basically, if the user doesn't need extra options, then don't give them extra options. You'll only confuse them.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old article, but it's still a great one:

[Microsoft Inductive User Interface Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997506.aspx)

Comment: I'll take Microsoft's advice on user interface design when they start producing products whose user interface aren't the dog's bollocks.

Comment: @Paul: And what would you be referring to as 'good' then?

Comment: @Paul: Strange. I know a lot of people who manage to use Microsoft products regularly. My grandmother, for instance.

Comment: There isn't good, there's only "less bad", and "more bad" (aka "Lotus Notes").  A lot of Apple software fits in the "less bad" category.

Comment: @Paul: It seems to me like writing off an article before you've even read it would fall under the "more bad" category.

Comment: @Paul: please check your prejudices at the door. Try reading the article, you might like it! If you can avoid seeing red every time you see the work "Microsoft", that is.

Comment: It's worth noting that even with the best research, implementation of the results is the hardest aspect of design.

Comment: Yes. But the implementation is exponentially harder when you're redesigning an already implemented UI. You want the UI to be as solid as possible so that it doesn't need to change.

Comment: @Adam Davis: very true. But the research helps. :)

Answer (score 6):

Never rely on anything that says "Are you sure?" The user is ALWAYS sure and that's if they even bothered to read it before dismissing.

Answer (score 4):

I'm of the school of thought that, in case of inclarities or ambiguousity, the user is rarely wrong, and the UI is always to blame. So, when you say "punch the user in the face", tagged with "pebkac", I'm thinking that *you* would do good with a slap in the face.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to give any good UX-advice, since I'm a mere programmer, and therefore more or less by definition disqualify as a good UI-designer. I'd like just to point out the possibility, that you actually could be the one who needs to get a clue, and try to be more humble towards the users.

***Edit for Adam:***

The little I know about UX is how little I know about it. It's an entire career path. I know for a fact that there's very little anyone can learn by asking a single make-me-good-at-this question at Stack Overflow. It's like me asking "help me write better code", with the body text formulated as a story of how my colleagues ridicule me of my code.

We, programmers, are engineers. We like order and reason and logical decisions. But the average user is not a programmer, not an engineer and, in many cases, not interested in computers themselves the very least bit.

I'm glad that people are giving you nuggets of good advice, and I'm glad that you, contrary to my first impression (I'm sorry about that), are eager to take those bits and understand the needs of the user.

But the point remains: You need to buy books (Don't Make Me Think is a great place to start, as already recommended). You need to watch how people use your software. You need to observe where they stumble, and jig things around until your UIs seem natural.

I'm sorry I still can't give you an answer. Because I don't have it. And even if I *would* have it, I would probably have to charge you 50EUR an hour, for years into the future.

Comment: Ah, and I thought I made it clear in my question that I know I need to change my design and practices.  Slap me if you desire, but the reality is that your answer isn't an answer at all, and has only given me information that I already know - I need to design for the user.  Now tell me how.

Comment: I actually have to side with this answer. Although you profess to see the need to change your designs, you still indicate that the problem lies with the users, and until your attitude is adjusted I seriously doubt you'll be able to make useful changes. This answer is "take ownership of the problem."

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly are you pointing out?  Are you merely objecting to the usage of "punch user in the face" and "pebkac", even in jest?  I realize these terms make light of a real problem with humility and programmers in general, but that's a digression from this question...

Comment: @overslacked - I'm not faulting the users at all.

Comment: @Adam - if that's true I think it'd be a good idea to remove the "pebkac" tag from this question. It's generally accepted to mean the user's chair, and not the developer's.

Comment: I think a major consideration is that even if there is a problem between the keyboard and the chair, it's still a devs job to design FOR that problem. If your program is usable by the most INFURIATINGLY dimwitted user, then your target audience will probably find it slick and useful.

Comment: @devinb - I completely agree with you. Drs, nurses and other clinicians are the bulk of my userbase and they are *remarkably* difficult. It took me far too long to realize the problem was mine alone, but my attitude adjustment has been the single most helpful change I've made.

Answer (score 4):

Partition your users and have fine-grained permissions.

Define some power-user permissions that enable the "more dangerous" operations.

Power user permission is not given out lightly -- only to actual power users -- and revoked readily.

Answer (score 3):

Make the results of the user's action visible and offer a way to undo those changes.

When the changes are visible, then the user gets feedback of whether the results were what he intended to do, and if they are not, then the possibility to undo will let the user to try again to reach his goal. If possible, make the results of the action visible before the user invokes the action (for example, when dragging some element, show what would happen if the user would release the mouse button, for example visualize addition of the element where it will be moved to and visualize the removal of the element from where it was moved from).

There are a couple of types of undo. The most simple is a single-step undo (as in Notepad), but it is often not enough. Better is a multi-step undo (as in Word), which covers most of the cases, but does not allow undoing a specific action without undoing all the actions that have been done after it. That can be solved by object-specific undo, for example in a form with many fields (or cells in a grid like in Excel), right-clicking the field would show a list of previous values in that field. For deleted data you could have a store of deleted data, from where the user can restore things after deleting them (for example if the user deletes a slide in Powerpoint). And finally you could have a full version history of every change, for example as [Local History](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/local_history.html) works in IntelliJ IDEA - make a history entry every time the file is saved (and save everything automatically after a couple seconds of inactivity).

Confirmation dialogs don't help. The user might read it the first time, but soon after that clicking "OK" in the dialog becomes an automated process, and the user will press Enter before the dialog even shows up. Then the confirmation dialog has become just a source of unnecessary mechanical work. The user is always sure about doing some action, even when he is wrong - otherwise he would not have done that action.

Comment: Very good point - it's hard to see what action has been taken until the user tries some other action later and gets unexpected results.  Make it immediately obvious what they just did.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a few different ways that I can/do go about these types of things.

1. User documentation - first and foremost give them some documentation to work with, and make the systems easy for them to use.  Just general usability and descriptive names/actions for everything.
2. Provide confirmation screens with warnings.  Full disclosure of what the action is going to do, with the warnings inside of a yellow box.  It draws attention to it and helps prevent the need for the other items.
3. Have a roll-back plan.  For large risky operations you can either simply set "deleted" flags, or offload the data to a temporary "recycle bin" of sorts should they accidentally remove/modify data that was unintended.
4. Require multiple approvals, for data purge operations especially go to a two-tiered approach, requiring approval from separate users.

These are just a few of the ideas that I have.

Comment: users don't read documentation. Providing the best documentation in the world won't make up for bad UI design.

Comment: confirmation screens also aren't a whole lot of use. Users too easily get in the habit of thinking "you're telling me what I already know" and click "ok". There are exceptions, of course. For example, I appreciate a confirmation screen before clicking the final "charge my credit card!" button.

Answer (score 1):

Two things immediately come to mind.

The first is the notion of progressive disclosure, i.e., only show users what they need in order to accomplish the task at hand.  How many UIs have we seen that have hundreds of controls on a single dialog?  Divide the controls into their respective tasks and only allow the user to do a single task at a time.  An Advanced button on a dialog is one way to implement this, and this concept has the added benefit of separating the power users from the run-of-the-mill users.  Run-of-the-mill users are less likely to attempt a task that is likely to be beyond their skill level.

The second is to leverage the wizard concept for complicated tasks.  I know wizards have fallen out of style, but if a task is truly complicated, users usually appreciate having their hands held the first few times.  A good example of this is the WinZip wizard interface.  If you've never zipped a file before, this wizard uses a logical progression to walk you through the process.  And then, once you've grown comfortable with it, you can switch to the classic interface to zip files more quickly.

Of course to do all of this requires a committment not only by the developers, but by management.  And that, sadly, is where many of these usability battles are lost.